# The usage of the modal verb "should" in a sentence

Tags: modal-verbs

I wonder what meaning of the verb "should" is used here in the sentence.

> I was surprised that he should say such a thing.

The sentence is from English Grammar in Use by Raymond Murphy. Unit 34, part D.

I totaly don't get it, what meaning does "should" have here?
My friend native said he doesn't know why here "should" is used, but said that I could easily replace it with "would" but I dont get it either, so I am here.

For me the sentence:

> I was surprised that he had said such a thing.

looks far better.
He commented the difference like:

1) It sounds like what he said is very out of character for him.

2) Here it's more simply surprise about what he said and doesn't really reflect on the person who said it.

Actually I don't get this explanation either, so I would like to see some detailed response to that subject.If it's correct rephrase that for me please. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Little is left of the **subjunctive mood** in English, but you have found a remnant!

"Should" is used in your first example to express the **subjunctive mood**. We use the form **should + bare infinitive** to express regret, annoyance, puzzlement, or surprise. Here, the compound form **should <s>to</s> say** emphasizes the surprise felt by the speaker, as the object of the "that" clause. Other examples:

> I regret that he **should feel** that way.
>   It's puzzling that he **should sing** that badly.

This usage is uncommon in NAmE, but might be heard in British usage. In either case, it might be seen as a little formal.

The alternative, **I was surprised that he had said such a thing,** doesn't quite express the same sense as the original. Your first try is a much closer match, and more likely to be heard in everyday speech:

> I was surprised that he **would say** such a thing.

**Should + bare infinitive** as subjunctive is also used after such verbs as "recommend," "propose," "insist," and "suggest:"

> The teacher insisted that he **should study** more.
>   My coach suggested that I **should take** a break.
>   I recommended that she **should dump** her boyfriend and date me.

Comment: Clear error: the OP's first example is **not** subjunctive at all, but an example of a specialised-modal 'attidudinal' _should_ construction expressing the speaker's subjective attitude or evaluation of something expressed in a subordinate content clause. This construction differs from the mandative in that the _should_ clause is not replaceable by a subjunctive, cf. *“I was surprised that he say such a thing”. Note also that the content clause is **not** object of "that" but complement to the adjective "surprised" which licenses it. (note also @Giambattista)

Comment: @PaulM, can you explan to me what the meaning is in terms of tenses? He said such a thing and after that I became surprised or what?

Comment: @Dmitrii Yes, that is correct. The sentence refers entirely to past time; it expresses the writer's surprise at hearing something that the referent of “he” had apparently said. But note that it is not a subjunctive construction. Subjunctives are usually mandatives like “It is essential that he be told immediately”; “He insisted that he be kept informed”, and such like, where the verb-form is an infinitive. “Say” in your example is an infinitive, but that’s because it heads a clause that is complement to the modal verb “should”; not because it is a subjunctive verb form.

Comment: @PaulM I missed the "replacement" test, and your analysis is spot on. Although the question has been marked as a dupe, you might reframe your comment above as an answer so that future searchers won't accept my error as correct.

Comment: By the way, I find this usage variously called the "putative should" and "evaluative should." Does anyone ( @PaulM ) have an authoritative reference, preferably from Lawler or someone of similar standing?

Comment: [link](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/155893/how-is-the-english-subjunctive-composed) . I need a cocktail now.

Answer (score 0):

It is a rather unusual an old-fashioned usage. The [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/should) offers this meaning:

> Used after "that" and adjectives or nouns that show an opinion or feeling.

Here are two more examples of this particular meaning:

> It's odd that she should think I would want to see her again.
>
> It's so unfair that she should have died so young.